# 'InitializeComponent not found in current context' in the Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use the xamarin.forms project in my personal project using the source rather than the nuget package.
I have added the projects to my solution and edited the reference of the Sample3 project to use the 'Xamarin' projects thai I have just added.
However I am facing the 'InitializeComponent not found in current context'. I have edited to references to point to the correct projects in this solution 
There are other answers that involve this question , but they are not dealing with the scenario that is just mentioned.

**Are there more projects that I need to add to the solution and edit the references?**

**In which project and class is InitializeComponent defined ?**

**What I need to do to get this working ?**[image]

**EDIT : The MainPage.xaml file**

[image]

Comment: can you please show your MainPage.xaml file?

Comment: please do NOT post code as images

Answer (score 0):

From shared image , Master Solution's name is **Sample2** , however your added project's Solution's name is **Sample3**.

[image]

If want to use `InitializeComponent` method , you should keep their namespace consistent .

Comment: I at first created the project named Sample2 but it gave the same error. Then while trying to find the solution I created a new project. I am not sure if that has caused the error.

Comment: @LearneriOS Okey, if new created projecrt also occurs this error, you can check VS whether installed is right .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2019